# Issues with Microsoft Teams Widget Permissions using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working on a Microsoft Teams Widget development project that involves utilising the `Graph API`. I've identified that I require some specific permissions to access assignments. To facilitate this, I created a new multitenant App and assigned these permissions to all users within my organisation via an admin account.

[image: permissions assigned]

However, upon attempting to log in using the admin account, I encountered the following message:

"No one else will be prompted to review these permissions."

[image: Signin Admin]

Strangely, after accepting the permissions, when I attempted to log in using a user's account, I faced a same issue:

[image]

This situation is occurring in my setup. I let an outside admin enable their users to use my app. I shared a consent link with them, and they gave permissions to all their users. When they tried to log in as a regular user, a message popped up saying that they needed admin approval. (They can see all the permissions they've given in their enterprise application.)

My goal is to enable users to sign in seamlessly, without being prompted to consent since they've already been assigned all the necessary permissions.

Has anyone else encountered this kind of scenario? How can I ensure that the assigned permissions are indeed accessible to all users, and why am I facing this inconsistency between the admin and user accounts? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.